# “Gathering evidence” vs. “Evidence-gathering”

Tags: adjectives, gerunds, adjective-phrases, gerund-clauses, participial-adjectives

I want to know, if there is any,  the difference between the following sentences:

> - **1**) He was responsible for **gathering evidence**. [gathering evidence](https://books.google.ca/books?id=QFq4CkuejckC&pg=PA81&dq=%E2%80%9Che%20was%20responsible%20for%20gathering%20evidence%E2%80%9D&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwier7TNn5HfAhUq5oMKHbTZAp8Q6AEIJTAA#v=onepage&q=%E2%80%9Che%20was%20responsible%20for%20gathering%20evidence%E2%80%9D&f=false)

And

> - **2**) He was responsible for **evidence-gathering**. [Evidence-gathering](https://books.google.ca/books?id=eHZYCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA12&dq=he%20is%20responsible%20for%20evidence-gathering%20locust&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwidjsWToJHfAhXp6YMKHfp-CnkQ6AEIJzAA#v=onepage&q=he%20is%20responsible%20for%20evidence-gathering%20locust&f=false)

---

Comment: Really, there's no difference. As a native English speaker, #2 sounds more casual and #1 a bit more formal, but ultimately they mean the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

The biggest difference is that on is a gerund (gathering evidence) and the other is a noun (evidence-gathering).  If you were making a list and wanted the language to be parallel, one list of responsibilities could be:

- Gathering evidence
- Interviewing witnesses
- Photographing the scene

Stated differently, the list would read:

- Evidence gathering
- Witnesses interviews
- Scene photographs

The meaning conveyed did not change despite the shift in language.